# Using 'in the current moment' or 'at the living moment'?

Tags: word-usage

I'm having a discussion with someone online and it takes each of us a day to respond, so I told him 
'We should converse at the current moment instead of after a few days', would there have been a better way to say this?

Comment: It's unclear what  you're trying to say.

Comment: 'We should do this right now'?

Comment: What language is this?

Comment: Do you mean "We should converse _in real time_"?

Comment: We should converse right away and not in a few days from now.

Answer (score 1):

The expression you're looking for is [**real time**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/real%20time):

> [Merriam-Webster]
>   : the actual time during which something takes place
>   // the computer may partly analyze the data in *real time* (as it comes in)
>   — R. H. March
>   // chatted online in *real time*

So:

- "This is taking too long. We should have a ***real-time*** **conversation**."
- "I don't like waiting to hear from you. We should **talk in** ***real time***."

Answer (score 0):

"Synchronous" is the classic term, but Jason's answer more modern.

- We should have a synchronous conversation. The asynchronous back and forth is taking too long.
- Email is an asynchronous form of communication. Instant messaging is a synchronous form of communication.

Comment: Is IM necessarily synchronous or has the term "live chat" taken over?  Either way, welcome to EL&U.  Please do take a moment for the [tour].

Comment: @livresque Technically, we would call IM synchronous if it used an underlying technology like TCP sockets. If it relies on other technology, like a database backend, we would call it asynchronous. Either way, the experience is practically a form of synchronous communication for the user. "Live chat" is a sales term--I believe.